# Explanation of Haskell subclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass

What's the relationship between the subclass relation and the fact that the methods of one class can be implemented using methods of some other typeclass?

For example, it's pretty confusing to me to define `Applicative` like `class Functor a => Applicative a` as that forces you to add a `Functor` instance before you can add the `Applicative` one, yet, you can write an instance declaration like `instance Applicative a => Functor a` that would make sure that every `Applicative` is also a `Functor`.

What's the reasoning behind the approach that's used? And, as I said, is it a rule that one typeclass is a superclass of another iff the superclass can be instantiated using the subclass?

Comment: I'd say it's not a rule. `class Num a => Fractional a` but you can't define `+` (in `Num`) using only the few methods of `Fractional`. That being said, it would be great if we could write e.g. an `instance Monad` and have `Applicative,Functor` automatically defined without boilerplate code. Or, better, some general mechanism for handing this in arbitrary class hierarchies...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a subclass as such, but a class restriction. In a class declaration, this usually indicates that the default polymorphic operations use polymorphic operations from that typeclass, though this is an exception.

Here, this doesn't matter, and is simply a restriction imposed, but it does mean that being an `Applicatve` instance means that an object is also a `Functor` instance, allowing `<$>` to be used without worry. How else would we manipulate the values within?

Remember that Haskell typicalness are just ways of describing polymorphic values: it is *not* equivalent to the structure of object-orientation.

The source for `Control.Applicative` can be found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Control-Applicative.html#Applicative), if you want to take a look at the actual declaration.